# Clarification of the license conditions of crossbario

Tags: licensing, crossbar, wamp-protocol

**[Update 2015-01-29]:** added some details of the scenario in question.

Just to make sure:
Do the licensen conditions allow to distribute and deploy the crossbar (crossbar.io, wamp, ...) stack in a commercial application?

Given that

1. We have a commercial application that is web based and  consists of several server modules.
   crossbar.io could be used to communicate between server processes and web clients.
2. We do **not** plan to open source our code
3. We will not modify crossbar.io
4. But we would like to deploy crossbar.io along with our product and install it with our setup tool.
5. Of course we would give credits and link to a local copy of the license file, for example in the about box.

Yes, I have looked at [AGPL 3.0](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/agpl-3.0.html) but I have to admit that I am not sure if the answer to my question is plain 'yes' or 'no'.

I am also aware that mongodb uses it. From the [mongodb licensing](http://www.mongodb.org/about/licensing/):

> To make the above practical, we promise that your client application which uses the database is a separate work. To facilitate this, the mongodb.org supported drivers (the part you link with your application) are released under Apache license, which is copyleft free.
>   Note: if you would like a signed letter asserting the above promise please contact MongoDB, Inc.

If I understand correctly, in order to use crossbar.io library in our scenario, it is importtant that our proprietary server code is considered 'separate work'.

Is it?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing and legal issues, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274964/1402846) for details, and the [help/on-topic] for more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Crossbar.io](http://crossbar.io/) is licensed under the [AGPL 3.0](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/agpl-3.0.html), the same license that e.g. MongoDB uses. The requirements of the AGPL 3.0 are listed in the license text.

Crossbar.io is *also* available under a commercial license as part of **Crossbar.io Enterprise Subscription** offered by [Tavendo](http://tavendo.com/).

Note that *connecting* a WAMP client to Crossbar.io does not affect, impose requirements on or restrict the license of the client.

Disclaimer: I am original author of Crossbar.io and work for Tavendo.

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to answer this. I looked at AGPL, but I am still uncertain. I added some details to the questions, that hopefully may allow a 'yes' or 'no' for an answer.

Comment: Yes, the critical distinction is between "derived work" and "separate work". The former requires you to follow the AGPL, the latter does not. We have the same scheme as MongoDB - all our WAMP client libraries are Apache 2.0 - no problem keeping your code closed. A WAMP client component is NOT considered a derived work, but separate. Note that "client" in this context is referring to "WAMP client vs router". It is irrelevant where a WAMP component runs. If you modify or extend Crossbar.io the AGPL kicks in. We'll add a clarification: https://github.com/crossbario/crossbar/issues/224